# Bootstrap4 navbar causes a problem for JQuery's parallax.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

First of all, I really do not know how to describe my problem. So, I ask you to check my JSFiddle Code Playground at the beginning.

https://jsfiddle.net/coming123/q46tjuev/

To see the problem, I want you to run this playground with a low width. Then, click to the "navbar-toggler" on the top left, which is provided by Bootstrap4's itself and a little bit desiged by me. When you click it, the navbar will be appeared from top to bottom on the right side. The problem appears at this point.

This navbar make the background became higher and makes the other contents move to bottom side. Scroll the page and you will see a bug appeared. background became higher but the parallax effect has been broken. Now you should make the area resized by pulling or pushing from sides. Just a little resizing will make this bug fixed. What I afraid is on mobile phones, you can not resize the browser. So the bug will not be fixed. Also I do not want it to be fixed by this way. I did not get why this problem appears.

I tried to make the div reloaded when you click the navbar-toggler but nothing has been fixed.

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("top");
var content = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML= content;  
console.log("Done");
});
```

Any suggestion?